# Differentiate function wrt. input of another function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

Good afternoon,

I have a function with multiple inputs one of which is a function, for example:
$T(u,w,y,v(x),z)$

Now $v(x)$ is a function of multiple inputs (parameters to a model):
$v(x) = G(p_1,p_2,p_3,...,p_n)$

As I change $ p_3$ value from h to $h+1$, I can see the impact the parameter has on $T(x)$, graphically. I seek to find the maximum of this impact curve and then optimise $v(x)$ by changing the value of another parameter,$ p_1$ such that the maximum $p_3$ impact occurs at a fixed point K. Changing the other parameters of v(x) changes the $p_3$ max impact magnitude and point K. This is okay, as I can recalibrate and reset $p_1$ value.

How do I differentiate $T(x)$ wrt $p_3$?

I imagine I can set this differential equation to $0$, to find a maximum, then run a Solver to optimise the value of p1, such that the differential $= 0.$

Sorry for math notation above not being optimal, first post.

Cheers,
Anthony

Comment: Utterly confusing if "$T(x)$" is $F(w,x,y,v(x),z)$, $T$ depends actually of $w,x,y,z$.

Comment: Yes sorry, T(w,x,y,v(x),z) not F

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly,  $x = (p_1,p_2,p_3,\dots,p_n)$. Apply simply the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) to  $T(w,p_1,p_2,p_3,\dots,p_n,y,v(p_1,p_2,p_3,\dots,p_n),z)$.

Comment: I can now see where the confusion was coming in, changed T inputs, so that variable x, is now u. Apologies.
That is T(u, w, y, v(p1,...pn),z)
Seeking dT/d(p3)

To make things interesting T is the Black-Scholes options pricing formula.